# Scanning Text through a chrome extension to auto launch links

Tags: google-chrome-extension, background, manifest

I'm pretty new at chrome extensions and am trying to make a simple one that automatically launches links in my emails.  I am going to modify it a bit later on, but for now, this is all I am trying to do.  How do I have a chrome extension automatically read the text of the current tab that I am on, or when I open emails if I can get that specific? I have a manifest file set up and currently can make the extension button launch a link, but I'd rather have this happen automatically, as I don't want to hit a button to launch a link when I could just click the link itself.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "MT task launcher",
  "description": "This extension launches Task Links in emails",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["task.js"]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Email Task Launcher"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

task.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  var action_url = "http://www.reddit.com";

  chrome.tabs.create({ url: action_url });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Official Guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions), for your purpose, I think you should use content scripts ( which are injected into current web page), then read the DOM and get all the links. To open the links, you can either call [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) or by passing message then open them via [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create)

Comment: Thanks, this actually helps me for what I need. However, do you know how to get this to work every time the url changes (ie, when I open an email). I have currently used the setInterval function, but obviously this is not idea. I have read about the chrome.tabs.onUpdated event, but I do not know where to put it.

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated is used in background scripts, you have to use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to ask content scripts to read all links and open them. Another good way is just to detect url change event in content scripts with pure javascript, you can take a look at [WindowEventHandlers.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange)

Answer (score -1):

There are two options to do that, it's either edit the local copy of the extension or to inject the call to the extension.

1. Inject code as a [Content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), use the matching rules as defines in the manifest file
2. A background page [file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) use the '*chrome.tabs.onUpdated*' [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated). Also, use the '*chrome.tabs.executeScript*' [method](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)  to inject script.